# How do you reference "current date" in a Metabase MongoDB native query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, metabase

I would like to use manual logic inside of a Metabase question. When referencing "Past 30 days" for example, the Metabase query builder can dynamically update the question to reference the current date. When converted to a native query, however, the dates convert to hard-coded dates eg. 2017-11-30. I've seen answers elsewhere suggesting "new Date()" etc but none of these will work within Metabase's native query editor. I'm looking for something like..

```
...
{
  "created_at": {"$gte": "new Date()"}
},
...
```

though this method does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Removing quotes from new Date().

Comment: @aeto Any updates ? I am also stuck with the same issue. Found something  but could not exactly find a solution. https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/4964

Answer (score 1):

### Using `new Date()`

As of v0.41, it seems like Metabase would accept the `new Date()` syntax and insert the server's date when writing it like so:

```
[{
    $group: {
        _id: new Date()
    }
}]
```

Proof of work on Metabase v0.41

[image: new Date() query on Metabase working]

Answer (score -3):

Take "new Date()" out of quotes, you're sending in a string.

```
{
  "created_at": {"$gte": new Date()}
}
```

Comment: Understood, though unfortunately in the Metabase native query world this does not work